# How to add css styles with JavaScript depending on the size of the browser

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, ecmascript-5

I am working with a Bootstrap 3 template and built a little JavaScript app. I am wanting to add a certain amount of margin to an element in one of the phases I created based on how big the viewport is. I have some code that I'm trying to work with but I keep getting the message Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined at MediaQueryList.myFunction. I cannot figure out why because all my variables that I am passing into the function as a parameter have values. I can see that the first value works because 17em is being applied but the value isn't changing when the size of the window changes. Disclaimer: I am fairly new to Javascript.

```js
var x = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 1200px)"),
  y = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 992px)"),
  z = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 768px)");


function myFunction(x, y, z) {
  if (x.matches && phase === phases.crustType) {

    doughSpan.style.marginLeft = "17em";


  } else if (y.matches && phase === phases.crustType) {
    doughSpan.style.marginLeft = "13em";


  } else if (z.matches && phase === phases.crustType) {
    doughSpan.style.marginLeft = "12em";


  } else {
    doughSpan.style.marginLeft = "0em";
  }

}

myFunction(x, y, z);

x.addListener(myFunction);
y.addListener(myFunction);
z.addListener(myFunction);
```

Comment: Have you considered using [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)?

Comment: I have but I created phases in JS and since I need to target one specific phase, I need to modify it with JS.

Comment: You'd be better off setting a class based off the phase then let media queries handle the rest. You can target that specific class from within the media queries.

Answer (score 2):

I'd handle this via media queries. It's what they are designed for.

Set a class on `doughSpan` based on the phase. You'd do this where you're setting phase. Let javascript handle the manipulation of the DOM and leave the styling of it to CSS.

Something along the lines of the following

```js
/*JS*/
function setPhase(phase) {
  //Add the class "paseCrustType" to doughSpan if that is the active phase
  doughSpan.classList.togggle("phaseCrustType", phase === phases.crustType);
  
}
```

```css
/*CSS*/
.phaseCrustType {
    margin-left: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .phaseCrustType {
    margin-left: 17em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .phaseCrustType {
    margin-left: 13em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .phaseCrustType {
    margin-left: 17em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, that makes sense! That didn't even cross my mind. I'll give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

When you call: `x.addListener(myFunction)`, `myFunction` is only being passed the `MediaQueryListEvent` for `x` when it expects all three. You should generalize the function to accept a single `MediaQueryListEvent` and a margin to apply, and call `addListener` for each of your media queries.

Here's an example:

```
var x = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 1200px)");
// declare y and z

var handleQuery = function(e, margin) {
  if (e.matches && phase === phases.crustType) { 
    doughSpan.style.marginLeft = margin;
  }
};

handleQuery(x, "17em");
// call handleQuery for y and z, passing along their margins

x.addListener(function(e) {
  handleQuery(e, "17em");
});

// call addListener for y and z and handle them as you need
```

Check out the [`MediaQueryList.addListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener) docs for more details.

Comment: That kind of works. The changes don't appear right away and I have to resize the browser a few times and then the margin size kicks in.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't pick up on that. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but for some reason it isn't working. Only the 17em is registering. It might have to do with my code?

Comment: If you could post a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) I'd be happy to take a look :)

Comment: That's so strange. It works in Codepen but not for me in Brackets and viewing it in Chrome. Hmmm. In addition to that, I am only wanting to have the margin changes in one phase (crustType) that is under the H4 tag titled Build Your Order but it is being carried over to the doughType_Prices_Size phase.

Comment: I updated the code so it only shows in the phase that I want. However, the margin changes kind of work but don't register when they are supposed to.